# THERE is error in syntax of triggers which im not able to fix, having pra1 table and pra1_audit trigger table for pra1

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, database-trigger

There is error in syntax of triggers which im not able to fix. I have `pra1` table and `pra1_audit` trigger table for `pra1`.

```
select * from pra1; 

CREATE TABLE pra1_audit  (     id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    id_menu INT NOT NULL,      id_productline INT NOT NULL, 
    Order_ID INT NOT NULL  );   


  DELIMITER $$  CREATE TRIGGER before_pra1_update   BEFORE UPDATE ON pra1  FOR EACH ROW   BEGIN  INSERT INTO pra1_audit  SET action = 'update',  id_menu= OLD.id_menu,  Order_ID = OLD.Order_ID; 
       END$$  DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `BEFORE UPDATE ON pra1` do you have pra1 as table?

Comment: yes  pra1 is a table

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? Bcz your syntax is wrong near you are inserting with update syntax `INSERT INTO pra1_audit SET...`

Comment: im  updating table pra1 and need to get the change inserted in pra1_audit table  with the column action ad update